# How to prevent HTTPS error between Apache server and Node Express?

Tags: node.js, apache, express, https

I have repurposed an old laptop to run Ubuntu Server 18.04.  On my local network I've given this laptop a fixed IP of 192.168.0.36, so that I can easily SSH into it from my main machine.

I am using the Apache server on this machine to host a website written in React (the single-page-application is built using `npm run build` and then copied to /var/www/html/).

Also on the laptop I have running an Express server listening on port 3305 (run using `node index.js`) which interfaces with a local MariaDb RDBMS instance, and relays JSON back to the website when called.

As I'm doing this from home I'm using noip.com to provide me with a URL that doesn't change every time my ISP dynamically changes my IP.

This all works fine under http; however I wish to add https encryption and therefore have used LetsEncrypt's certbot to add a certificate to my Apache configuration.

Unfortunately now when I look at the https version of my React page, no data is pulled through from the database and the browser gives me the following error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxx.hopto.org' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://192.168.0.36:3305/contract/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

This is straightforward - but also confusing.  The Express server listening on port 3305 is behind Apache running on a local machine, so by implication 'trustworthy.'

I am fairly sure the problem comes down to how I am trying to connect my React application and this Express server, which is done like so:

**App.js (React website)**

```js
getContract = _ => {
        fetch('http://192.168.0.36:3305/contract/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => this.setState({ contract_list: response.data }))
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
```

**index.js (Node express server)**

```js
const app = express();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.host,
    user: config.user,
    password: config.password,
    database: config.database
});
app.use(cors());
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send('go to /contract to see contracts')
});
const SELECT_ALL_CONTRACT_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM contract';
app.get('/contract', (req, res) => {
    connection.query(SELECT_ALL_CONTRACT_QUERY, (err, results) => {
        if(err) {
            return res.send(err)
        }
        else {
            return res.json({
                data: results
            })
        }
    });
});
app.listen(3305, () => {
    console.log('Db server listening on port 3305')
});
```

I have attempted to change App.js so it fetches from `http://localhost:3305/contract` but this simply fails to connect.  I have also tried making the Express server provide https, but this involves a self signed certificate, which just leads to different errors.

My hunch is that I need to dive into my Apache configuration and let it know that it is looking at the local machine rather than external, but I have nil experience of this...

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much, much reading I found the answer, and it did lie in Apache configuration:

#### 1. Amend the App.js fetch to a relative link

Using my code example above:

**App.js (React website)**

```js
getContract = _ => {
        fetch('/api/contract/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => this.setState({ contract_list: response.data }))
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
```

This then gets chunked on the end of the referring URL, so if you call it from https://example.org then the URL it points to (in the above example) is https://example.org/api/contract/.  Interestingly it doesn't seem to make a difference whether you put the backslash in front of *api* or not, but I thought it made more sense that way.

#### 2. Install required modules in Apache

At the command line enter:

```sh
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_html
```

#### 3. Amend Apache configuration

In both files */etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf* and */etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf* add the following text (within the *<VirtualHost...>* tags) :

```sh
ProxyPass /.well-known/ !
ProxyPass /api http://127.0.0.1:3305
ProxyPassReverse /api http://127.0.0.1:3305
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

The first file (*000-default.conf*) redirects calls to http (i.e. port 80) and the second (*000-default-le-ssl.conf*) redirects for https (i.e. port 443).  Not sure these are the configuration files for all Apache set ups, but they worked for me.

This tells Apache that any incoming traffic for a URL ending in */api* should be sent to localhost (127.0.0.1 in my case) on whatever port Express is listening on (3305 in my example).

#### 4. Restart Apache

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`

---

Now once you have conducted whatever you consider the appropriate ritual to the God of SysAdmins, try the URL and it should work...

Although this was a combination of a couple of sources, hands down the most useful was [Proxying Node application through Apache](https://handyman.dulare.com/proxying-node-application-through-apache/).